# Rollout restart statefulset using kubectl proxy

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-statefulset

I have started kubectl proxy from within my pods and am able to access kubernetes APIs. I have a need to restart my statefulset.

Using kubectl, I would done this:

```
kubectl rollout restart statefulset my-statefulset
```

However, I would like to do this using the REST APIs. For instance, I can delete my pods, using this:

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods
```

Is there any equivalent REST endpoint that I can use to rollout restart a statefulset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run your command `kubectl rollout restart statefulset my-statefulset --v 10` and notice the output logs.

I figured out  `kubectl` makes a patch request when I apply above command. And I am able to do that patch request using **curl** like following

```
curl -k --data '{"spec":{"template":{"metadata":{"annotations":{"kubectl.kubrnetes.io/restartedAt":"'"$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%T%z)"'"}}}}}'\ 
    -XPATCH   -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "Content-Type: application/strategic-merge-patch+json"\
    localhost:8080/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/statefulsets/my-statefulset
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer as well as tip for future investigation.